# How to prevent cURL joining multiple `--data` values by &-symbol?

Tags: command-line, curl

I'm using cURL to put some data onto a Redmine server. I want to use multiple `--data-xxx` options to build a valid XML request body. The command is like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/xml" \
  -H "X-Redmine-API-Key: $TOKEN" \
  -d "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><wiki_page><text>" \
  --data-binary "@$FILE" \
  -d "</text></wiki_page>" \
  -X PUT http://some.redmine.site.com/projects/someproj/wiki/test.xml
```

However, as `--data` option documented:

> If any of these options is used more than once on the same command line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a separating &-symbol. Thus, using `-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy` would generate a post chunk that looks like `name=daniel&skill=lousy`.

I can understand the designer of cURL make it this way to help build a URL with query string. But in this situation, these added &-symbols will make my request XML body malformed. I can prepend "nbsp;" to the value to workaround this when it's after `--data`. But when it comes to the usage mixed with a file (`--data-binary "@$FILE"`), there are no way to work this out.

Comment: Sadly, I've read the manpage carefully and I can tell there is no option to change or suppress the interconnecting character. The only way I can think of is to complete concatenating the string before do curl.

Comment: I think this question belongs to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass everything as a single `--data` value, then. There are several ways you could do it:

- For short files, 'include' the file's raw contents in the command:

  ```
  curl … -d "<?xml…?><wiki_page><text>$(cat "$FILE")</text></wiki_page>"
  ```
- For longer files, create a temporary file containing the required data:

  ```
  temp=$(mktemp /tmp/redmineXXXXXXXX.xml)
  {
      echo "<?xml…>"
      echo "<wiki_page><text>"
      cat "$FILE"
      echo "</text></wiki_page>"
  } > "$temp"
  curl … -d "@$temp"
  rm -f "$temp"
  ```

Comment: Thanks @grawity. Yep, there *are* several ways to do it indeed and I'll take one of them. Last words: whether cURL should provide an option to let users change this? Besides the case I brought up above, [matrix-parameter URI](https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html) also engages semicolon as the separator rather than the ampersand.

Comment: No, it shouldn't, because `-d` is **not for building URIs – it's for building POST data**. Specifically, it generates `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` formatted POST data, which _always_ uses `&` as the separator. While this format is based on URI query strings, it is _not the same thing._

Comment: I tried to post multiple data reusing tcp connection to same url and multiple `-d` needs to use `--next` and repeat same url and headers too as same as multiple `-d`. on another hand piping to curl doesn't work too `for i in {0..9};do echo "post_$i" done | curl -H ".." https://url -d @-`  doesn't work